# Copy and Paste Data using Office Script

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts

I am trying to create a power automation cloud flow. At first I was using a macro but then realised that I cannot run macros with power automate cloud flows. So instead I opted to create a office script to do the same process as the macro.
What I want is for the script to match a certain cell on one sheet to a column in another, then copy the corresponding row data and paste it into certain cells.
My idea is to use the submitted responses from a microsoft forms. The flow will auto populate the cell K7 on Sheet 1. Then the script matches that to the row A on Form1. Then copy and paste.

I have tried many different ways but cannot figure it out. I only have the office script type set. Please see my code below as well as the error i'm getting.

Error:Line 10: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  function copyDataFromFormToSheet(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet 1");
    let sheet2 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet 2");
    let form1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Form1");

    let valueToMatch = sheet1.getRange("K7").getValue();
    let matchColumn = form1.getRange("A:A").getValues();

    for (let i = 0; i < matchColumn.length; i++) {
      if (matchColumn[i][0] === valueToMatch) {
        let rowToCopy = i + 1;

        sheet2.getRange("H1").setValue(form1.getRange(`E${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
        sheet2.getRange("H3").setValue(form1.getRange(`B${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
        sheet2.getRange("H5").setValue(form1.getRange(`A${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
        sheet2.getRange("C10").setValue(form1.getRange(`G${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
        sheet2.getRange("C12").setValue(form1.getRange(`H${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
        sheet2.getRange("C14").setValue(form1.getRange(`I${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
        sheet2.getRange("C15").setValue(form1.getRange(`J${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
        sheet2.getRange("C16").setValue(form1.getRange(`K${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
        sheet2.getRange("C17").setValue(form1.getRange(`L${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
        sheet2.getRange("C20").setValue(form1.getRange(`M${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
        sheet2.getRange("C22").setValue(form1.getRange(`N${rowToCopy}`).getValue());

        break; // Once matched, exit the loop
      }
    }
  }

  copyDataFromFormToSheet(workbook);
}
```

I have tried many different ways of organising the code but I am limited to office typescripts.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is close to finish.

- In OfficeScript, `form1.getRange("A:A").getValues()` returns `null`. Then line 10 raises the error.
- There are several options to get the last row index.
- Row index is zero-base. Don't forget `adding 1` when you use it in `getRange()`.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    function copyDataFromFormToSheet(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
        let sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet 1");
        let sheet2 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet 2");
        let form1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Form1");

        let valueToMatch = sheet1.getRange("K7").getValue();
        let lastRow = form1.getRange("A:A").getLastCell().getRangeEdge(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.up).getRowIndex()+1;
        let matchColumn = form1.getRange("A1:A" + lastRow.toString()).getValues();
        for (let i = 0; i < matchColumn.length; i++) {
            if (matchColumn[i][0] === valueToMatch) {
                let rowToCopy = i + 1;
                sheet2.getRange("H1").setValue(form1.getRange(`E${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
                sheet2.getRange("H3").setValue(form1.getRange(`B${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
                sheet2.getRange("H5").setValue(form1.getRange(`A${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
                sheet2.getRange("C10").setValue(form1.getRange(`G${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
                sheet2.getRange("C12").setValue(form1.getRange(`H${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
                sheet2.getRange("C14").setValue(form1.getRange(`I${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
                sheet2.getRange("C15").setValue(form1.getRange(`J${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
                sheet2.getRange("C16").setValue(form1.getRange(`K${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
                sheet2.getRange("C17").setValue(form1.getRange(`L${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
                sheet2.getRange("C20").setValue(form1.getRange(`M${rowToCopy}`).getValue());
                sheet2.getRange("C22").setValue(form1.getRange(`N${rowToCopy}`).getValue());

                break; // Once matched, exit the loop
            }
        }
    }

    copyDataFromFormToSheet(workbook);
}
```

Comment: This works perfect thank you kindly for your help. 
Do you know how I would then save "Sheet2" as a PDF in the same place that the excel is located? Then clear the sheet afterwards ready to be ran again?

Comment: Power Automate can [convert Excel to PDF](https://www.muhimbi.com/guides/pdf-converter/power-automate/excel-to-pdf/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=paid_search&utm_campaign=power-automate&utm_content=excel-to-pdf&utm_term=power%20automate%20convert%20excel%20to%20pdf&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiA98WrBhAYEiwA2WvhOjcZ3tEh66NSrfjtzA3uo_PqrovgoKMMHpQRwFw_8ZzWGevhcTZjHhoC9uMQAvD_BwE).  Office Script can't do it as VBA does.

Comment: Ah unfortunately due to my business restrictions I cannot use Muhimbi. Do you know of any other ways?

Comment: Do you mean PA? Office Scipts doesn't support saving as PDF.

Comment: Yeah in PA. I can't create any connections to external parties so I am limited to the base PA cloud flows